# PicklingError while trying to save an object that uses two separate instances of another class

Tags: python, pickle, xgboost, joblib

I am getting `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'xgboost_distribution.distributions.base.Predictions'>: it's not the same object as xgboost_distribution.distributions.base.Predictions` error while trying to dump custom model to file using the following code:

```
import joblib
from xgboost_distribution import XGBDistribution

class XGBTransportEstimator:

    def __init__(self, cost_params, time_params):
        self.cost_predictor = XGBDistributionWrapper(cost_params)
        self.time_predictor = XGBDistributionWrapper(time_params)

    def fit(self, X, y_costs, y_times, **kwargs):
        self.cost_predictor.fit(X, y_costs, sample_weights=None, **kwargs)
        self.time_predictor.fit(X, y_times, sample_weights=None, **kwargs)

    def predict(self, X):
        costs_pred = self.cost_predictor.predict(X)
        times_pred = self.time_predictor.predict(X)
        return costs_pred, times_pred

class XGBDistributionWrapper:

    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self.predictor = XGBDistribution(**parameters)

    def fit(self, X_train, y_train, sample_weights, **kwargs):
        self.predictor.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=sample_weights, **kwargs)

    def predict(self, X):
        preds = self.predictor.predict(X)
        return preds.loc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xgboost = XGBTransportEstimator(cost_params, time_params)
    xgboost.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train_costs,
        y_train_times
    )
    joblib.dump(xgboost, 'xgboost_model.jpkl')
```

Strangely, when I remove the line with fitting one of two models inside `XGBTransportEstimator` class, saving to file works fine (without the mentioned error). So the problem is not caused by the fact that `XGBDistribution` class cannot be pickled. It seems to be related with using two instances of this class simultaneously.

I wonder if this is caused by the implementation of `xgboost-distribution` package or I am missing something in my code?

Comment: Is it possible that you're using a very outdated version of `xgboost_distribution`?  There was code added in September 2021 to make the `Predictions` class (a namedtuple) pickleable.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm using the newest version of that package (0.2.6 from 2023-01-21).